# POST without POST data?

Tags: php

I am using the following statement to check for post data and set a variable if it comes through via the URL:

```
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
   {
     $sort = $_GET['sort'];
   } else {
     $sort = "mgap_ska_id";     
   }
```

I need the variable to be assigned a value via POST, but only if the value is passed through the URL. If the URL doesn't contain the variable, the value needs to the a string I can pass to a query. Is it better to use  if/then or is some other method better?

Thanks

Comment: If the variable comes via the URL it can never be POST.

Comment: your question makes no sense, you need the variable to be assigned a value from POST but only if its passed through the URL (i.e. via GET)..? what?

Comment: Should probably be `$sort = $_POST['sort'];`

Comment: @ToBe `$sort` will not be what you think it is. Read the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two conditions:

### If it's a post request

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
}
```

### Use the get variable if present

```
$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'mgap_ska_id';
```

### Just put them together:

```
$sort = 'default'; // If it's a get request

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'mgap_ska_id';
}
```

Comment: Ok that is working fine and verified by print_r, but now my variable is not found in my query:  ORDER BY $sort";

Comment: did you check under the sofa?

Comment: I checked there first..:)

Comment: There is no mention of that (a query) in the question, but that sounds unrelated to what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

just check

```
if(isset($_GET['sort']){
  $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}
else{
  $sort = "mgap_ska_id";
}
```

but don't forget to check for valid data. Never trust a users input.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a form input field named "sort":

```
$sort = '';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    // Sent by POST
    $sort = $_POST['sort'];
} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    // Sent by GET
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
} else {
    // Neither - set a default.
    $sort = "mgap_ska_id
}
echo $sort;
```

Answer (score 0):

also you may try following will work with POST and GET Methods

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sort']){
  $sort = $_REQUEST['sort'];
}
else{
  $sort = "mgap_ska_id";
}
```

For your reference

- You should use $_GET when someone is requesting data from your
  application.
- And you should use $_POST when someone is pushing (inserting or
  updating ; or deleting) data to your application.

Either way, there will not be much of a difference about performances : the difference will be negligible, compared to what the rest of your script will do.